# How to store a document with details in a document library?

Tags: document-library

I have a document library in SharePoint and I want to store the document with metadata to SharePoint  document library. Is this possible?

Comment: What type of details you want to store? Do you have separate columns in Document Library for those details?

Comment: What do you think SharePoint is for? Certainly you can store documents and metadata about the documents!

Comment: That edit did not really help calrifying the question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You can Create your own Custom Column as per your Requirements.Then,When you Upload Documents that Column also appear to fill data.You can fill data & that will be the Detail of that particular Uploaded Documents.

Comment: +1, nice answer

Answer (score 2):

You can create columns in a library. All the column value will also be stored in the document properties too. The properties can even be seen if downloaded to a local drive and checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following link for uploading documents with details using code behind. You should initially create necessary columns in document library.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514557/upload-documents-to-sharepoint-with-metadata-c-sharp-asp-net

Comment: you will add documents from code behind or through page?

Comment: Then you can update the document library columns from code behind know. If you need those columns to be automatically populated, you need to have content controls in that word document and map those content controls with your document library columns using Document Information Panel(DIP).